# Oracle DB, creating unique constraint on multiple columns for insert , how about performance

Tags: database, oracle, performance

Friends,

Am new to DB venture, I needed some help/information. 
 There is a table in our project say "record_table" , values in it is inserted using C++ code.

This table has multiple columns, out of which three columns say for eg. "serialNo, type, sub_type" that C++ code is inserting duplicate values for combination of these columns( these columns are no where unique or primary for that table). But the combination of 3 columns should be unique.

Now we want to make sure duplicates for this combination shouldnt be inserted. I was thinking of adding unique constraint for these columns so that when new record is to be inserted with these duplicated values it will not allow to .

I assume this should work, but I have a doubt will it hit the performance, the C++ binary runs daily and it inserts around 2 million records. Will creating unique constraint hit performance.(Mean will the run time slow down or since the table has millions of records will creating unique constraint make no sense as it has to make a hash of these columns etc)

Please suggest if you can.

Answer (score 5):

Unique constraints are enforced through an index. Chances are you need that index anyway, for querying the data back again, so the overhead of maintaining it is irrelevant.

The real question is, what is the performance impact of handling duplicate records if you don't enforce the constraint? Generally speaking the performance impact of enforcing constraints is trivial compared to fixing data corruption.

Comment: Good answer. Plus 2 million inserts per day is pretty small.

Comment: 730m records a year isn't that tiny for most people @BobC. You're required to put some thought into infrastructure and data architecture at that point, especially if the load isn't equally distributed throughout the day. Just buying the licence to deal with that is gonna get expensive quickly if you aren't paying attention.

Comment: I agree with @Ben - compared to the Twitter firehose two million inserts is pretty small, but for most RDBMS applications it's a lot: enough to merit some forethought. If you haven't dealt with such data volumes before it's easy to come unstuck.

Comment: Well the question was more about performance vs data volumes. I agree that these things need to be thought about, but I have a system that I use for training and demos, that does about 40,000 transactions a second. So if you say that 2 million inserts per day is over 8 hours (rather than 24), then that is less that 70 transactions per second. That should be within the capability of my laptop.

Comment: Thanks for reply and suggestions you all put. For my case, the C++ batch job runs once a day for few hours and that is where it does data massaging and inserts around 2 M records in the table. I am planning to use unique constraint for POC and try to check the difference for time execution compared to when constraint is not added. Will keep you all posted.